# Exclusion lists when crawling web directories

Tags: web-crawling

I have a case where I'm building a connector between a federated search engine, and an archive that's serving all of their data via HTTP.  They've been kind enough to have their pipeline generate a series of index files for each day that I can use to get the metadata that I need to allow people to search through their data.

Often for situations like this, I'd use `wget` to get directory listings ... but I'm running into a few problems:

1. Some of the directories are *huge* ... it's taking me minutes for the 'day' directories (and this spans a decade).
2. They have the autoindex options set so that they also have links to sort the directory in different ways.
3. I need to check for signs of re-processing, so I'll need to re-crawl, it's not just a one-off crawl.

I was hoping to use `wget` to skip over the sorting links, as more recent versions allow rejection patterns, instead of just rejecting file extensions:

```
-R '*index.html[?]C=?;O=?'
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the 'exclude' option in wget doesn't do quite what I'd have expected:

> ```
> 2015-03-25 14:35:33 (6.30 MB/s) - `index.html?C=N;O=D' saved [2635]
>
> Removing index.html?C=N;O=D since it should be rejected.
> ```

... so it downloads the files, and then deletes them ... rather than avoiding them in the first place.

Is anyone aware of a tool that can be used for scraping that processes a reject list *before* attempting to download things?

Comment: Does this also happen with the `--reject-regex` option?

Comment: @Kersten : hmm ... it seems that I'm running an older wget that doesn't support that option.  Compiling the most recent wget now.

Comment: @Kersten : I tried `--regex-type pcre --reject-regex '.*index[.]html[?]C=\w;O=\w'` but it's not even deleting them.  Will try some more after my meeting in 2 min.

Comment: I should add that I had the same problem with the `index.html*` files. I circumvented that by using the `--spider` option, then filtered the resulting url list and used wget with the filtered list to download the files. From your question I am not quite sure if that is even an option.

Comment: @Kersten : I tried it, and got the message of `Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.`, but it still does the 'download, but then delete' behavior.  I *really* don't want to contacting the remote webserver at all.  I guess I could set up an HTTP proxy, and have that do the filtering.  Your mention of `--spider` also led me to : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2804467/143791 ... which sounds like what I need, but I suspect I might need to do `--convert-links` and write a wrapper to only pull one URL at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Using `--reject-regex "\?.=.;.=."` seems to work for me to avoid the extra listings provided by Apache. The full command-line I use to get all the files from an Apache directory listing is:

```
wget --recursive --no-parent --timestamping --no-directories --reject-regex "\?.=.;.=." http://example.com/some/dir/
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't solve the problem entirely, but I'll add it here for anyone else who has the same issue.  (but not mark it as the answer, in case someone else has a better solution)

There's a program [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) which allows you to retrieve a URL and extract information from the page using XPath queries.  See [this response to a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16466719/143791).

The problem is that it doesn't do two things:

- **recursive retrieval** -- you'll have to write your own script process the output and do whatever logic you need to determine what links to follow.
- **return complete URLs** -- the example shows how to extract what's in `//a/@href`, but this could be an absolute, relative or root-relative instance.  It may also need to take `//base/@href` into consideration if one exists.

Even with those problems, I found that it saved me considerable time over trying to get `wget` to do what I needed.  I called xidel in a perl script, and then used `curl -s -f -z` (silent, no file on failure, send if-modifed since) to do the file retrieval once I identified the proper URLs to check for updates.  I probably could've used LWP::Simple's mirror() to avoid calling out to curl.